# where is defined the: `this.props` referenced on the first line inside the `render()` function?

Tags: react-native, jsx, expo

On the following code:

1. where is defined the: `this.props` referenced on the first line inside the `render()` function? Is there any relationship between that lowercase: `props` variable with the capitalized `Props` type? any convention here?
2. what implication has: `...extends React.Component<Props>`?
3. what implication has the `/* @flow */` line on the very top of the file?

https://github.com/callstack/react-native-paper/blob/e4ca933f386d7b485f6580c332f0638a55dfe2db/example/src/CardExample.js#L27

```
/* @flow */

import * as React from 'react';
import { Alert, ScrollView, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import {
  Title,
  Caption,
  Paragraph,
  Card,
  Button,
  withTheme,
  type Theme,
} from 'react-native-paper';

type Props = {
  theme: Theme,
};

class CardExample extends React.Component<Props> {
  static title = 'Card';

  render() {
    const {
      theme: {
        colors: { background },
      },
    } = this.props;
    return (
      <ScrollView
        style={[styles.container, { backgroundColor: background }]}
        contentContainerStyle={styles.content}
      >
        <Card style={styles.card}>
          <Card.Cover source={require('../assets/wrecked-ship.jpg')} />
          <Card.Content>
            <Title>Abandoned Ship</Title>
            <Paragraph>
              The Abandoned Ship is a wrecked ship located on Route 108 in
              Hoenn, originally being a ship named the S.S. Cactus. The second
              part of the ship can only be accessed by using Dive and contains
              the Scanner.
            </Paragraph>
          </Card.Content>
        </Card>
        <Card style={styles.card}>
          <Card.Cover source={require('../assets/forest.jpg')} />
          <Card.Actions>
            <Button onPress={() => {}}>Share</Button>
            <Button onPress={() => {}}>Explore</Button>
          </Card.Actions>
        </Card>
        <Card style={styles.card}>
          <Card.Content>
            <Title>Berries</Title>
            <Caption>Omega Ruby</Caption>
            <Paragraph>
              Dotted around the Hoenn region, you will find loamy soil, many of
              which are housing berries. Once you have picked the berries, then
              you have the ability to use that loamy soil to grow your own
              berries. These can be any berry and will require attention to get
              the best crop.
            </Paragraph>
          </Card.Content>
        </Card>
        <Card style={styles.card}>
          <Title>Just Strawberries</Title>
          <Card.Cover source={require('../assets/strawberries.jpg')} />
        </Card>
        <Card
          style={styles.card}
          onPress={() => {
            Alert.alert('The Chameleon is Pressed');
          }}
        >
          <Card.Cover source={require('../assets/chameleon.jpg')} />
          <Card.Content>
            <Title>Pressable Chameleon</Title>
            <Paragraph>
              This is a pressable chameleon. If you press me, I will alert.
            </Paragraph>
          </Card.Content>
        </Card>
        <Card
          style={styles.card}
          onLongPress={() => {
            Alert.alert('The City is Long Pressed');
          }}
        >
          <Card.Cover source={require('../assets/city.jpg')} />
          <Card.Content>
            <Title>Long Pressable City</Title>
            <Paragraph>
              This is a long press only city. If you long press me, I will
              alert.
            </Paragraph>
          </Card.Content>
        </Card>
      </ScrollView>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  content: {
    padding: 4,
  },
  card: {
    margin: 4,
  },
});

export default withTheme(CardExample);
```

Could you give me some light on this?

**References:**

https://flow.org/en/docs/react/components/

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

1. props is defined in Component (is in base class) because you have FLOW this.props should have shape of Props )
2. You are extending base Component and you component can accept "Props" shape data in your example you component will accept a property theme of shape "Props".
3. Flow is static typing to JavaScript (https://github.com/facebook/flow || https://flow.org/)

Comment: why if I remove: `/* @flow */` from the very top, then the application continues working properly (with no errors at all)?, then what's the reason to have that annotation in there?